# Beautiful text - typography

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, typography

Can anyone show me how to draw something like this. I am thinking of having a quote with similar font but have no idea where to start.

[image]

Comment: Please indicate what the "similar font" might be.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As a start you can look around in [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) for similar fonts, and maybe use the [`pgfornament`](http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/ornament/index.html) package for drawing ornaments. (Note that you'll have to manually download the `pgfornament` package from the indicated link and copy to your “project folder.”)

Also I've made a small solution, so you may start along this way.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Zapf Chancery font: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/zapfchan/
\usepackage{chancery}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

% pgfornament package: http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/ornament/index.html
\usepackage{pgfornament}

\usepackage[active, tightpage]{preview}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength{\PreviewBorder}{1mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % some necessary lengths for the
    % calculation of the length of the ornament
    \newdimen\SWXcoord
    \newdimen\SWYcoord
    \newdimen\SEXcoord
    \newdimen\SEYcoord
    \newdimen\ornamentwidth

    % text
    \node[align=center,%
        anchor=base,
        inner xsep=3em,
        inner ysep=0pt,
        outer sep=0pt] (text-node) at (0, 0) {
            Virgo
        };

    % calculate the width of the ornament
    \path (text-node.south west);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\SWXcoord}{\SWYcoord}
    \path (text-node.south east);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\SEXcoord}{\SEYcoord}
    \ornamentwidth=\SEXcoord-\SWXcoord

    % ornament
    \node[align=center,
        anchor=south,
        inner sep=0pt,
        outer sep=0pt,
        yscale=-1,
        xscale=-1] (ornament-node) at (0, 0) {
            \pgfornament[width=\ornamentwidth]{79}
        };

    % line between the text and the ornament
    \draw ($(ornament-node.south west) + (1em, 0)$) -- ($(ornament-node.south east) + (-1em, 0)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```